# Representing a object list in XSD

Tags: java, xsd

I need to declare a list in my xsd file . Not sure what changes do I need to make. I tried using simple type but the required type is not getting generated.

**I need my pojo to have the datatype as -**

```
  @XmlElement(name = "Journeys", required = true)
        protected List<LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier> journeys = new ArrayList<LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier>();
```

**My current xsd**

```
                    <xs:complexType name="AccountLoyaltyDetail">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="OperatingCompany" type="ns:OperatingCompanyType"
                    minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Journeys" type="ns:LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier" />
                <xs:element name="Segments" type="ns:LoyaltySegmentIdentifier" />
            </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier">
            <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="JourneyIdentifierId" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Free form text to be echoed back in the reply.
                                    Used to match requests and replies.</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                  </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType
```

>
**currently the pojo is generated as -**

```
@XmlElement(name = "Journeys", required = true)
    protected LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier journeys;
```

Please let me know what changes do I need to make

Answer (score 2):

To represent a List in XSD use complexType, not xs:list.
Your XSD needs change as follows.

```
<xs:complexType name="AccountLoyaltyDetail">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="OperatingCompany" type="ns:OperatingCompanyType"
                    minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Journeys" type="LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier" />
                <xs:element name="Segments" type="LoyaltySegmentIdentifier" />
            </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier">
            <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="JourneyIdentifierId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:documentation>Free form text to be echoed back in the reply.
                                    Used to match requests and replies.</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                  </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Let's see the difference between `xs:list` and `xs:complexType` now.
The purpose of `xs:list` element is not to represent a Collection type, It only lists the similar type of elements as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="stringvalues" type="valuelist"/>

<xs:simpleType name="valuelist">
   <xs:list itemType="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

The "stringvalues" element in a document could look like this (notice
 that the list will have four list items):

```
<stringvalues>I love XML Schema</stringvalues>
```

Now, To represent the java.util.List in XSD, use below example. List is just a complex type with maxOccurs attribute value as unbounded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">       
    <xsd:element name="customer">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="phone-number" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ... But when I am trying changing my xsd as suggested .I am getting the pojo as provided above not like what I need . Also , I want my list to be of object type .can you tell me what change do I have do for that

Comment: I am getting error as " It was detected that 'LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier' has no namespace, but components with no target namespace are not referenceable from schema 
 document 'file:///D:/ILoyalty_WS/Loyalty_WS/src/main/config/properties/contract/xsds/SxgyService.xsd'. If 'LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier' is intended to have a namespace, perhaps a prefix needs to be provided. If it is 
 intended that 'LoyaltyJourneyIdentifier' has no namespace, then an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should be added to 'file:///D:/ILoyalty_WS/Loyalty_WS/src/main/config/properties/contract/xsds/

Comment: @themaster: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32906291/983430) for how to fix that error. Basically, you just need to reference your current target namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me, you can create from wsdl as well as xsd

> Following is the object you want list of

```
<xs:complexType name="objectClass">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
                nillable="true" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

> Refer this object in other adding min occurrence and max like following

```
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item"
                type="tns:objectClass" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

> Above would result in java like following

```
public class MainClassWhereYouWantListofAboveClass {
       protected List<objectClass> item;
       //.....
}
```